# "Member access 'DataType MemberName' of 'Namespace.ClassName' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Namespace.ClassName]."

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I would love a solution to my current problem, but I would love EVEN MORE if I can understand what that error actually means.

I have LINQ to SQL classes for two tables in my DB: **Providers** and **Assignments**. I added the following member to the Provider class:

```
public IEnumerable<Assignment> Assignments 
    {
        get
        {
            return (new linqDataContext())
                .Assignments
                .Where(a => a.ProviderID == this.ProviderID);
        }
    }
```

Then, I bind a GridView using a query that pulls from the parent **Provider** and uses the child member **Assignments**, like this:

```
protected void PopulateProviders()
    {
        linqDataContext context = new linqDataContext();
        var list = from p in context.Providers
                   where (p.Assignments.Count(a => a.Category == ddlCategory.SelectedValue) > 0)
                   select p;

        lvProviders.DataSource = list;
        lvProviders.DataBind();
    }
```

At .DataBind(), when it actually runs the query, it throws the following error:

> Member access 'System.String Category' of 'Namespace.Assignment' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Namespace.Assignment].

I've tried checking for nulls (a => a != null && a.Category ...) but that hasn't worked. I'm not sure what to try next. I think that, if I knew what the error is trying to tell me, I could find the solution. As it stands, I don't know why member access would be illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `Assignments` property is all wrong.  First of all, property getters should not have side-effects, and more importantly, entity classes should never have reverse dependencies on the `DataContext`.  Linq to SQL has no way to decipher this query; it's relying on a property that does all sorts of crazy stuff that Linq to SQL can't hope to understand.

Get rid of that `Assignments` property *now*.  Instead of doing that, you need to write this query as a join:

```
int category = (int)ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
var providers =
    from p in context.Providers
    join a in context.Assignments
        on p.ProviderID equals a.ProviderID
        into g
    where g.Count(ga => ga.Category == category) > 0
    select p;
```

That should do what you're trying to do if I understood the intent of your code correctly.

One last side note: You never dispose properly of the `DataContext` in any of your methods.  You should wrap it like so:

```
using (var context = new linqDataContext())
{
    // Get the data here
}
```

Comment: Awesome. An extra point to you for "letting me have it". Thanks for helping me learn something important.

Comment: @Byron: Lol, apologies if it came off as a rant, it was my best attempt at an explanation of why L2S was choking - it saw the expression and went "OMG WTF" like I did. :P

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere it doesn't know that type that is in the IEnumerable. You are trying to call a method that is not part of the IEnumerable inteface.

Why don't you just move the query from the property out to the PopulateProviders() method?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your custom-defined Assignments property. In the your Linq-To-SQL dbml file, create an association between Providers and Assignments, with Providers as the parent property, and ProviderID as the Participating Property for both entities. LINQ will generate a property "IEnumerable Assignments" based on matches between ProviderID using a consistent DataContext.